# Integration limit for Probability Distribution function

Tags: integration, probability-distributions

Suppose that the random variables Y1 and Y2 have joint probability density function f ( y1 , y2 ) given by:

```
f(y1, y2) = {
                6 * y1^2 * y2, if 0 <= y1 <= y2, y1 + y2 <= 2
                0, elsewhere
            }
```

**Question:**

What is P(y1 + y2 < 1)?

I am having a hard time finding the limits of integration for y1 and y2.

**For y1 I got this so far:**

We know that `y1 >= 0` (from the original question), `y1 <= 2 - y2` (from the original question), and finally `y1 < 1 - y2`.

The answer says that the limit of integration for `y1` goes from `0 to 1/2`. I don't understand how they got `0 to 1/2` from these three inequalities from y1. Can someone please help me understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps it will be better to rewrite in terms of $x,y$.
$$
f(x,y) = \begin{cases}
6x^2 y & 0 \le x \le y \text{ and } x+y \le 2 \\
0 & \text{ else} 
\end{cases}
$$
If you plot the above region, then it looks like a triangle . . . Easiest to describe in "integrals" as $dy \, dx$ not $dx\, dy$, since the latter would require the sum of two integrals.

The largest $x$ value is the intersection of $y=x$ and $y=2-x$ i.e. when $x=1$. So we can check that the pdf integrates to one:

$$1 =  \int_{0}^1 \int_x^{2-x} 6x^2 y \; dy \, dx$$

Now, for $P(x+y <1)$, we integrate the pdf over $\mathbb{1}_{x+y<1} = \begin{cases} 1 & x+y<1 \\ 0 & \text{else,} \end{cases}$ meaning ignore places where $x+y \ge 1$. This in effect restricts our region of integration to $0 \le x \le y$ and $x+y <1$. Here the largest $x$ value is the intersection of $y=x$ and $y=1-x$, which is $x=1/2$.
$$
P(x+y<1) = \int_{0}^1 \int_x^{2-x} \mathbb{1}_{x+y<1} 6x^2 y \; dy \, dx
=  \int_0^{1/2}  \int_{x}^{1-x} 6x^2 y \; dy \, dx = \cdots = \frac{1}{32}
$$

Comment: Sorry for the late response. But when plotting this: 0 ≤ x ≤ y Do you plot `x = y`, `x >= 0`, and `y >= 0` and then bound that by the `x + y <= 2`?

Comment: Not quite - heres $x \le y$: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+x%3C%3Dy and then you need to only consider $x \ge 0$. Then you consider the intersection of that with $x+y \le 2$. The final graph looks like this: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+0%3C%3Dx%3C%3Dy+and++x%2By+%3C%3D2